# Segmentation faults doing nested loops in assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm writing an assembly program for an assignment where I need to take an array, let's say

```
array:  DB  1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

and I need to loop through it and print a star corresponding to the number in the array. So in the example above the program should output:

```
* * * * *
  * * * *
    * * *
      * *
        *
```

My problem is I'm getting Segmentation faults somewhere in the code and I can't pinpoint where. Anyone have any idea where this is happening?

code:

```
%INCLUDE    "csci224.inc"

SEGMENT     .data
array:      DB      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
star:       DB      "*",0,10
n:          DB      0

SEGMENT     .text
main:
    mov         edx, 9                  ;length of array
    mov         ecx, 0                  ;loop counter
    jmp         outerloop               ;begin outerloop

outerloop:

    mov         ah, [array+ecx]         ;move (array element + loop counter) to ah

    movzx       ebx, ah                 ;zero extend ah to ebx
    mov         [n], ebx                ;copy value of array element to variable
    mov         eax, ebx

    inc         ecx

    ;call       WriteInt    
    dec         edx
    jnz         innerloop               ;jump to innerloop

innerloop:                              ;cycle through '[n]', printing a star each time
        mov     edi, [n]
        mov     eax, [star]
        call    WriteString             ;print star
        dec     edi                     ;decrement counter
        jnz     innerloop               ;is edi zero? if no, loop again
        cmp     ecx, byte 0             ;if yes, go back to outerloop
        jz      outerloop


    ret
```

Comment: you can find out where the segmentation fault occurs by using a debugger. do you know how to do that? i recommend gdb.

Comment: `n` is only a byte, and you're moving a dword in and out of it! `mov eax, [star]` ("[contents]") is almost certainly supposed to be `mov eax, star` (address). You may need to save and restore `ebx`, `esi`, and `edi` around `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the `ret` you have at the end, is not the correct way to end your program!  In Windows, you would use `ExitProcess` or call `exit` if you are linking to the C library.  In Linux, you would use `int 80H - sys_exit` or `syscall - 60` or `exit` if you are linking to the C Library.

When using nested loops, first get your outer loop working first; print out each value in the array.  Once you have that working, add your "inner" loop to print the stars.

In the following code, I use `esi` and `ebx` since those must be saved by the callee so we shouldn't need to worry about saving those values.

```
extern printf, exit
global main

SEGMENT     .data
array:      DB      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
array_len   equ     $ - array
star:       DB      "*", 0

SEGMENT     .text
main:
    mov     esi, 0                  ;loop counter

.ArrayLoop:
    ;~ Get array value to use as PrintStars loop counter, esi is index into array
    movzx   ebx, byte [array + esi]
    ;~ increase ArrayLoop "Outer Loop" counter
    inc     esi
    cmp     esi, array_len
    ;~ if esi > array_len, we are done
    jg      .Done   

.PrintStars:
    ;~ print stars here

    ;~ decrease "Inner Loop" counter
    dec     ebx
    ;~ If ebx != 0, continue "Inner Loop"
    jnz     .PrintStars

    ;~ ebx == 0, print new line char and continue "Outer Loop"    
    ;~ print newline char here
    jmp     .ArrayLoop

.Done:
    call    exit
```

Which would print out the stars as:
[image: Star thing] according to the array in your source.

If you wanted to make a pyramid, read [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/302352-nasmwindows-lets-create-a-pyramid-of-characters/)